# WP7 how pivot control works?

Tags: windows-phone-7, header, pivot, large-data

I'm building Windows Phone 7 application that shows a large image gallery. I'm using pivot control to show them.

The pivot has `HeaderTemplate` that contains 1 `TextBlock` (the title of the picture) and `ItemTemplate` that contains 1 `Image` control (the picture).

Supposed my gallery contains 300 pictures. When I choose 300th picture, I see the `Image` show the 300th picture instantly, but the header shows gradually from the 1st to the 300th title.

Why do the header NOT show the 300th title instantly ? How to force it to show instantly ?

Is there a better implementation of pivot the handle huge amount of item ?

Comment: It is by design. What do you actually want?

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek I want to force it to show title instantly. Does it load all 300 pictures, or just the 300th picture ?

Comment: Because 300 is the _last_, the transition effect is by design. Are you satisfied with the transition between 299 and 300?

Comment: You really should not use Pivot for displaying hundrets of images. It was designed for showing separate pages, about 10 max. You should consider using something like SlideView here: http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/slideview.aspx

Comment: @MartinSuchan it's a paid one :( is there anyway to implement a better pivot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as many items as you want. Just use DataBinding and nothing else. No codebehind and no manually usercontroll adding. Just use Templates as you already did and all works fine. Why?

Templates and databinding has the concept, that only the data will change. If you will see scroll downl the huge list, in real only the content of items will change. The list itselfes will only stay ... for example 10 items + 2 (top/bottom) and will be filled with data of x-thousend of entries if needed. The memory only needs to show about 12 items not hunderts or thousends by using databinding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

For checking your situation, you can add any timer to the MainPage and check the RAM usage:

```
Private Sub dptm_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles dptm.Tick
    txtDeviceUsedMemory.Text = "Speichernutzung : " & (Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage / 1024 / 1024).ToString("0.0") & "MB"
End Sub
```

[image: Databinding]

Comment: but pivot with 1000 items costs more memory than pivot with  100 items. It seems that pivot create UI container for all its items ?

Comment: It depends on how you will work with it. If you use only ONE single item as "Template" it will works fine. If you will add 1000 pivot pages at MainPageLoad event, it will use RAM.

Comment: I do use databinding for my pivot, the binding source has 1000 items. I want to know if pivot create 1000 UI container for those 1000 items ?

Comment: What do you mean with "Pivot"? Pivot Pages = 1000 Pivot pages? Or one single Pivot page like in the sample with a list of "1000 items"? Also have a look to my example of "RAM using" which can help you almost.